# Formula of escape velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, escape-velocity

While establishing relation of escape velocity and radius , I confronted a problem .

(i) $$v_e=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R}}$$

This states that $v_e$ is inversely proportional to the square root of radius .

(i) $$v_e=\sqrt{2gR}$$

This states that $v_e$ is directly proportional to the square root of radius .

**Whoch one’s correct?**

Comment: The two formulas do not contradict, because they do not use the same variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write a relationship between two variables $x$ and $y$  as $y \propto x$ you can also write this as $y=kx$ where $k$ is a constant independent of $x$ and $y$.

Assume  that $R$ is the radius of the planet, $M$.

Using your first equation you stated that the escape velocity $v_{\rm c}$ is inversely proportional to the square root of the radius, $\sqrt R$, provided that the mass, $M$, is constant.
But you have a problem because assuming that it is a homogeneous spherical planet of density $\rho$ the mass $M = \frac 43 \pi R^3 \rho$ and the mass depends on the radius so what you assumed to be a constant, $2GM$,  is not independent of the radius.

For the second equation you are saying that the escape velocity $v_{\rm c}$ is proportional to the square root of the radius, $\sqrt R$, provided  $g$ is constant.
However $g = \frac{GM}{R^2}$ so it is in fact also dependent on $R$ thus invalidating your second proportionality.

You can however show that if the density is constant then the escape velocity from a homogeneous spherical planet is proportional to the radius of the planet.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is solved when you realize that $g$ in your second formula is a function of $R$: if

$$F = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

is rewritten as

$$F = mg$$

Then it follows that

$$g = \frac{GM}{r^2}$$

When you substitute that in your second equation, you get the first...

Comment: That means the correct relation is obtained from the first one ..

Comment: They are both correct if your second one has the square root for the whole thing.

Comment: How come ...? Isnt that condradictory?

Comment: It is not contradictory. If you found yourself in a very high orbit (say out near the moon), you could escape the earth's gravity from there with a smaller velocity than you would need close to earth. The second equation you have expresses things relative to the _local gravity_ at the height where you are (which itself drops off with inverse square of distance to center of earth). So rather than considering $g$ constant and getting confused, you should recognize it's really $g(r)$, expand the expression, and realize there is no contradiction.

Comment: Thank you ... that is , the *g* in the second one is a function of R ... there are two variables ...

Answer (score 3):

You can derive the scape velocity by calculating the energy at the surface and then at infinity

$$
E_{\rm surf} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 -G\frac{M m}{R} \tag{1}
$$

You want to find $v$ such that the mass $m$ reaches infinity $r\to\infty$ with zero velocity, that is

$$
E_{\inf} = 0 \tag{2}
$$

If you put these two equations together

$$
\frac{1}{2}mv_e^2 - G\frac{Mm}{R} = 0 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ v_e = \left(\frac{2GM}{R}\right)^{1/2} \tag{3}
$$

But now, the force that $m$ feels on the surface is

$$
F = -G\frac{Mm}{R^2} = -\left(\frac{G M}{R^2}\right)m = -g m ~~~\mbox{with}~~~ g = \frac{GM}{R^2}\tag{4}
$$

Replacing Eq. (4) in Eq. (3) you get

$$
v_e = \left(2 g R\right)^{1/2} \tag{5}
$$

Comment: Would you please kindly state the correct relation between *g* and *R* ?

Comment: @A.H.M. Please look at the last part of Eq. (4)

Answer (score 2):

$g$ is defined as:
$$g=\frac{GM}{R^2}$$

The escape velocity is:

$$v_{e}=\left(\frac{2GM}{R}\right)^{0.5}$$

You can write this equation in terms of $g$ doing this trick:

$$v_{e}=\left(\frac{2GM}{R}\frac{R}{R}\right)^{0.5}=\left(2\frac{GM}{R^2}R\right)^{0.5}=\left(2gR\right)^{0.5}$$